# 'Type' cannot satisfy the 'new()' constraint on parameter 'TParam' because 'Type' has required members

Tags: c#, generics, .net-7.0

I have this class structure (simplified):

```cs
public class InducingMedium
{
   public required string File { get; set; }
}

public class InducingVideo : InducingMedium {}
public class InducingAudio : InducingMedium {}
```

Now, I want to generically instantiate an instance of a specific type:

```cs
public abstract class BaseInducingTests<TMedium>
    where TMedium : InducingMedium, new()
{
   protected async Task<IEnumerable<TMedium>> CreateInducingMedia(IEnumerable<string> files)
   {
      return files.Select(file =>
      {
          // Do some processing...

          return new TMedium
          {
              File = file,
          };
      });
   }
}

public class InducingVideosTests : BaseInducingTests<InducingVideo>
{
}
```

But in the derived class I get an error:

```
'Namespace.InducingVideo' cannot satisfy the 'new()' constraint 
on parameter 'TMedium' in the generic class 'Namespace.Tests.BaseInducingTests<TMedium>' 
because 'Namespace.InducingVideo' has required members
```

Is there any way to fix this without introducing reflection?
I was really excited about `required` members, which work pretty well with nullable types, but now I see this has its own caveats :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explicitly mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required):

> A type with any required members may not be used as a type argument when the type parameter includes the new() constraint. The compiler can't enforce that all required members are initialized in the generic code.

Either remove the `required` modifier or change the generic handling. For example provide factory via ctor:

```cs
public abstract class BaseInducingTests<TMedium>
    where TMedium : InducingMedium
{
    private readonly Func<string, TMedium> _init;

    public BaseInducingTests(Func<string, TMedium> init)
    {
        _init = init;
    }
    protected async Task<IEnumerable<TMedium>> CreateInducingMedia(IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        return files.Select(file => _init(file));
    }
}

public class InducingVideosTests : BaseInducingTests<InducingVideo>
{
    public InducingVideosTests() : base(s => new InducingVideo{File = s})
    {
    }
}
```

If needed you can then create a wrapper to support classes which satisfy `new()` constraint:

```cs
public abstract class BaseNewableInducingTests<TMedium> : BaseInducingTests<TMedium>
    where TMedium : InducingMedium, new()
{
    protected BaseNewableInducingTests() : base(s => new TMedium { File = s })
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround which I've just found is `SetsRequiredMembers` attribute:

```
public class InducingVideosTests : BaseInducingTests<TestInducingVideo>
{
}

public class TestInducingVideo : InducingVideo
{
    [SetsRequiredMembers]
    public TestInducingVideo()
    {
    }
}
```

This kind of defeats the purpose of `required` members, but so does reflection and for test purposes it's an easier way.

Source: https://code-maze.com/csharp-required-members/

Comment: Note - this is also mentioned in the docs (referenced in my answer) with a warning: _"The `SetsRequiredMembers` disables the compiler's checks that all required members are initialized when an object is created. Use it with caution."_, one reason being - it does not even check if ctor actually does what  is claimed (i.e. sets `File` in this case).